# How to learn and show gridview rows includes "?" data 

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, gridview

There is a gridview which includes 6 columns. I bound the data to some columns. For example, 3 and 5 th columns have data.
I want to show There is 2 data in first columns if there is 3 data in separate columns I want to write 3 in the first column.

```
Column1   |   Column2   |   Column3    |   Column4   |   Column5    |   Column6

  2       |             |    stack     |             |   overflow   |

  4       |   sta       |    ck        |     over    |     flow     |

  1       |             |              |             |              |  stcvrflw
```

How can I do it?

I populate the grid 
e.Row.Cells[i].Text = html;

and html variable includes < table>.... some values come from db.

Comment: how are you populating the gridview?

Comment: check this sample @ http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51889/Summary-DataGridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you populate the grid:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            valueCount=0;
            for (int j = 1; j < gv.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
              if (gv.Rows[i].Cells[j].ToString()!="")
                  valueCount++;
            }
             gv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text =valueCount.ToString();  
        }
```

Comment: it gives below error:
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'

Comment: I copy and paste your code and I have changed 'gv' with my gridview id.. and when I compile it I get indexing error as you see.